# Program exited with status value:255. while debbuging iphone app in device

Tags: iphone, debugging

My app is crashing with an error code - Program exited with status value:255. I can't find any error or stack trace in console. This crash will occur only when the app is installed and executed for the first time. I don't get this error while running the app second time. I searched around the web and found a solution. According to that I changed the Target setting of "Compile for Thumb" to off. Even after I am getting this crash and error.

In my previous versions i don't get this error. I don't know whether any change in the code or settings of Xcode causing this problem.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Adarsh V C.